# How to pass a value from controller in a button to the next blade?

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass the value from this controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
  $data_show = DB::select("SELECT * FROM staffs WHERE id = ?", [$id]);
  $data_profil = DB::select("SELECT id FROM staffs WHERE id = ?", [$id]);
  return view('keluarga.index', compact('data_show', 'data_profil'));
}
```

Passing the value to this blade:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <!--add new button  -->
      <div class="col-lg-2">
          {!! Form::open(['route' => 'addkeluarga_form', $data_profil->id]) !!}

          {{ Form::submit('Add New', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

          {!! Form::close() !!}
      </div>
      <!-- show all button -->
      <div class="col-lg-1">
          {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1">
          {{ Form::submit('Cancel', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) }}
      </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

This is add new button which bring the staff id to the add new blade. But it fail to read the value of id in the blade.

How to fix this?

Comment: You probably want to store this in a session variable. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to write

```
$data_profil = DB::table("staffs")->select("id")->whereId($id)->first();
```

**BUT** it doesn't make any sense, as you already have $id in your controller. There is no point on retrieving it again from the DB.

Pass **$id** to the template and use it instead

**return view( 'keluarga.index', compact('data_show', 'id') );**

Comment: the select syntax works...only that this button doesn't read the value

Comment: {!! Form::open(['route' => 'addkeluarga_form', $data_profil->id]) !!}
 this code cannot read array value

Comment: $data_profil is a collection. Should use ->first() or something to narrow the results to one. I will update my answer

Comment: thanks! How I want to pass id to the template...sorry for silly question. i am a beginner...

Comment: take a look at the answer: just compact it and return it to the view

Answer (score 0):

check if the `data_profil` variable is containing your expectation using the print_r() method. i.e

```
$data_profil = DB::select("SELECT id FROM staffs WHERE id = ?", [$id]);
print_r($data_profil);//you will comment this out latter
```

check on the top of your page the content of your variable, I you see a nested array output like `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 , ...))` , then you may want to refer your variable as an array in your template. i.e.

```
$data_profil[0]->id
```

Comment: thank you for sharing...i will use your method in other function. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For the first query get all column, 
and for secound query I don't think that you need to get id, as you already have id.

```
$data_show = DB::table("staffs")->where('id',$id)->first();
$data_profil = $data_show->id;
OR
$id = $id; // As the same id it will return

return view('keluarga.index', compact('data_show', 'data_profil','id'));
```